# What does ~0 do?

Tags: c++, c, bitwise-operators, bit

---

Does ~0 mean its flipping 000000000 to 1111111111?

```
printf("Check: %i", ~0);
```

The printf results to -1, which is why I am confused.

Does -1 essentially mean the same thing as 11111111111111111 bits?

Comment: first hit on google http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4ab.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Does ~0 mean its flipping 000000000 to 1111111111?

Yes, it does.

> Does -1 essentially mean the same thing as 11111111111111111 bits?

In [2s complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation, it does.

Comment: I'm used to someone beating me to the answer (slow typing here), but typically they don't grab nine upvotes too!  A tip of the hat to you.

Comment: @AustinTruong `~0` does not evaluate in `1111111111` unless `int` is internally only 10 bits. Same issue with second part.

Answer (score 6):

```
Does ~0 mean its flipping 000000000 to 1111111111?
```

Yes, that's what it means.

```
printf("Check: %i", ~0);

The printf results to -1, which is why I am confused.
```

That's because of 2's complement arithmetic, where we have conventionally accepted zero to be

```
000000000000
```

and subtracting one from it requires a "borrow" that requires a borrow, and so on, until you "roll" the entire register

```
111111111111
```

Logically, if you add "1" to that number, it will carry, and carry, and so on until it "rolls" in the opposite direction, yielding `000000000` again.

```
Does -1 essentially mean the same thing as 11111111111111111 bits?
```

Yes, as long as you are using 2's complement signed integers.

---- Edited, to include details from cincutar's now deleted post (I wish he didn't delete it) ---

To see the same memory formatted as a (unsigned) hexadecimal number, use the command

```
printf("Check: %x", ~0);
```

which will print the output

```
Check ffffffff
```

which is (for those who don't read hexadecimal well)

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
```

Answer (score 3):

`~0 == 0xFFFFFFFF`

where  `0xFFFFFFFF`= 32 times 1 , which is -1 in [2's compliement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation

since `~` is a bitwise operation and turns zero to one in each bit:

```
~0b1010 == 0b0101
```

Answer (score 3):

It is due to the mathematical operation "two's complement". A nice video tutorial of two's complement can be found on youtube. Here's one of them :)

[youtube link](http://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CDsQtwIwAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D9W67I2zzAfo&ei=1x5BUNaXGuqRiQeK_4CQDg&usg=AFQjCNHf2V56pIyKyMJmorD_esT4iFpDBQ)